# ¿Cómo crear un screen splash en base color de fondo más logo al abrir la aplicación?

Tags: react-native, expo

Tengo la siguiente estructura, que me permite crear una loading antes de mostrar contenido de la App:

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './Splash';

export default class App extends React.Component {
    
    state = {
        loaded: false
    }
    constructor() {
        super();
        Splash.load(v => this.setState({loaded: true}));
    }

    render() {
        return(
        <View style={styles.container}>
            {this.state.loaded ? <Text>Welcome!</Text> : <Text>Loading...</Text>}
        </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Splash.js

```
export default class Splash {
    static load(cb){
        setTimeout(cb, 3000);
    }
}
```

Lo que quiero es mostrar un color de fondo más el logo al abrir la aplicación y pasados ​​unos x segundos se muestra el contenido.

Esto es lo que deseo lograr:

Al abrir la app:
[image]

Después mostrar contenido/información:

[image]

En base al planteamiento de mi código que cambios debo emplear, estoy segura que son unos pequeños cambios que lastimosamente no encuentro ejemplo en la web para poderlo lograr.

Comment: Vas a usar React-navigation?

Comment: @fabrixo96 Soy nueva en React por ahora en los tutoriales se va usar `React-navigation` v5 no sé si exista alguna otra forma de hacerlo ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La mejor forma de implementar un Splash Screen es usando React-Navigation ya que haciendo uso de este podemos tener el manejo de que vista podemos poner de primeras y pues de la misma forma en toda la respectiva navegacion de la app

Primero, Si no tienes React navigation lo istalas de la siguiente forma

```
npm install @react-navigation/native
```

y

```
expo install react-native-gesture-handler react-native-reanimated react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

por ultimo para el ejemplo vamos a utilizar la navegacion de tipo Stack para la cual necesitamos instalar la siguiente libreria igualmente

```
npm install @react-navigation/stack
```

Vamos a empezar a abordarlo creando 2 vistas, Splash.js y Menu.js para luego en el App.js importarlas y que se muestren

en Splash pones esto

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,Image, View } from 'react-native';


export default class Splash extends React.Component {
  
goToScreen(routeName){
  this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName)
}

componentDidMount(){

  setTimeout( () => {
    this.goToScreen('Menu')
  }, 2000, this)//2000 hace referencia al tiempo, eso lo puedes cambiar a tu gusto
}

  render(){
  return (  
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Image source = { require('./RutaDeLaImagen' ) }/>
    </View>
    
  );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#33B747',
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center",
  
  }
});
```

Luego en la vista Menu

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet,View,Text } from 'react-native';


export default class Menu extends React.Component {


render(){
return (  
    <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text>Menu</Text>
    </View>
    
);
}
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#FFF',
    alignItems:"center",
    justifyContent:"center",

}
});
```

Por ultimo en App.js tendriamos que importar Splash y Menu, crear la navegacion

```
import React from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './screens/Splash';
import Menu from './screens/Menu';

const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default class App extends React.Component{

    render(){
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu}/>
        </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );      
    }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
        alignItems: 'center',
        justifyContent: 'center',
    }
});
```

Si te das cuenta dentro de `<Stack.Navigator>` pongo de primeras el Splash, esto se hace para que sea la primera vista en renderizas

Eso seria, debes tener en cuenta cambiar las rutas de la imagen y de las importaciones de app.js dependiendo de la estructura de archivos de tu proyecto

Si se me pasa algun error me disculpas, lo hice sin probar

Animo, sigue aprendiendo y llenandote de nuevas cosas

Comment: Gracias por el aporte, soy programadora en PHP, hasta ahora no se me hace difícil adaptarme aún nuevo lenguaje  :) solo hasta entender todo su sintaxis de manera correcta :)

Comment: Si existe alguna depuración de error tratare de solucionarlo por mi misma en caso de no lograrlo te comento, nuevamente gracias.

Comment: Todos nos destacamos en algo, en mi caso de php no es de mi agrado pero react si me gusta un poquito mas jaja, con el tiempo te adaptas a esto de los componentes, funciones, etc

Comment: @ fabrixo96 tengo un error amigo en agregar imagen `import logo from './assets/logo.png';` la imagen esta alojado en la ruta...

Comment: He creado una nueva pregunta en base al problema de la imagen: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414175/error-en-importar-o-agregar-imagen-en-expo-react-native para probar el código proporcionado, reemplace la imagen agregando un texto `<Text>Hola</Text>` en sí, el código funciona sin error excepto del problema de la imagen, pero amigo en la parte superior me crea una cabecera o un `header` al pasar al Menu en esa parte superior me crea lo siguiente [ <- Menu ] si doy click en esa flecha del `header` este me devuelve al loading o splash y ahí me mantiene

Comment: Esto no debería ocurrir ya que dicha funcionalidad del `screen loading` o `splash` es solo mostrarlo cuando el usuario abra la aplicación o cuando exista un enlace y se abra dentro de ella, no se si me hago entender amigo.

Comment: si, te entiendo... para ocultar el header de la vista menu le debes agregar la opcion de headerShown:false al igual que esta en Splash en el archivo App.js. entonces quedaria asi <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Menu} options={{headerShown:false}}/>

Comment: Gracias un nuevo hilo si me deseas guiar :) https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/414228/c%c3%b3mo-combinar-un-toptabnavigator-y-bottomtabnavigator-expo-react-native