# ¿Error en importar o agregar imagen en EXPO React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo

Al ejecutar el proyecto me imprime el siguiente mensaje de error:

> Unable to resolve "./assets/logo.png" from "app\resources\views\screens\Splash.js"

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Image, View } from 'react-native';
import logo from './assets/logo.png';
```

Cabe recalcar que la imagen esta alojada correctamente en el directorio y, la forma como la intento agregar es:

```
<Image source={logo} style={{ width: 305, height: 159 }} />
```

- Documentación de agregar imagen: https://docs.expo.io/tutorial/image/

Comment: no veo ningun error, en react hay casos en el que no reconoce los cambios hechos en el codigo,  para lo cual en algunos casos es mejor cerrar la aplicacion por completo y volver a ejecutarla, para limpiar cache entre otras cosas...

Comment: @fabrixo96 Existe alguna línea de comando CMD Windows para detener la carpeta del proyecto o la ejecución de la misma y a la misma vez eliminar el cache algo así `npm stop nombreproyecto --clean cache`

Comment: @fabrixo96 Si cerré el proyecto y lo volví a ejecutar pero me seguía saliendo ese mensaje de error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Según la documentación de [`EXPO` Images / Static Image Resources](https://docs.expo.io/versions/v36.0.0/react-native/images/):

> Muchas de las imágenes que mostrará en su aplicación no estarán disponibles en el momento de la compilación, o querrá cargar algunas de forma dinámica para mantener el tamaño binario bajo.

A diferencia de los recursos estáticos, deberá especificar manualmente las dimensiones de su imagen . Se recomienda encarecidamente que utilice https también para satisfacer los requisitos de seguridad de transporte de aplicaciones en iOS.

```
// GOOD
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}}
       style={{width: 400, height: 400}} />

// BAD
<Image source={{uri: 'https://facebook.github.io/react/logo-og.png'}} />
```

React Native proporciona una forma unificada de administrar imágenes y otros activos multimedia en sus aplicaciones de Android e iOS. Para agregar una imagen estática a su aplicación, colóquela en algún lugar de su árbol de código fuente y haga referencia a ella de esta manera:

```
<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />
```

> Pero al realizarlo de esa manera esta ejecutando error, debe ser por las indicaciones dadas al principio de mi respuesta.

Si existe otra alternativa que solucione este problema: `<Image source={require('./my-icon.png')} />` no estaría de más conocer alguna solución.

Answer (score 0):

Modificar la extensión de la imagen de la siguiente forma:
imagen.png por imagen.android.png ó imagen.ios.png y finalmente
<Image source={require('./assets/img/imagen.android.png')}/>