# ¿Cómo combinar un TopTabNavigator y BottomTabNavigator Expo React Native?

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

En el siguiente código obtengo como resultado, el `loading -> screen splash` y, luego cargar el `Home` con el respectivo `tabTop` superior, pero el problema que presento ahora es agregar otro `Tab` pero esta vez en un `TabBottom` inferior.

Este es mi código:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/bottom-tabs';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity, Button } from 'react-native';
import Splash from './app/resources/views/screens/Splash';
import Menu from './app/resources/views/screens/Menu';

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const Tab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

function Home() {
    return (
        <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="Destacado" component={Menu} />
        </Tab.Navigator>
    );
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <NavigationContainer>
                <Stack.Navigator>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
                    <Stack.Screen name="Menu" component={Home} />
                </Stack.Navigator>
            </NavigationContainer>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

Pero en el ejemplo para implementar un `tabBottom` utilizan las misma estructura de código que el `tabTop`, pero no puedo combinarlo de manera correcta.

---

Después de la solución dada y, una largo estudio he estructurado mejor el tema de navegación, teniendo lo siguiente, pero presentando el mismo problema anterior sobre agregar `tabs` superior y, rescatar el nombre del `tabs` inferior activo para así mostrarlo en la cabecera de la aplicación:

```
import React from 'react';
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation-stack';
import { createBottomTabNavigator } from 'react-navigation-tabs';
import { createAppContainer } from 'react-navigation';
import { MaterialIcons, MaterialCommunityIcons } from '@expo/vector-icons';

import Splash from '../screens/Splash';
import NewsListScreen from '../screens/NewsListScreen';
import NewsItemScreen from '../screens/NewsItemScreen';


const StackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    //Splash: {screen: Splash},
    News: {
        screen: NewsListScreen
    },
    NewsItem: {
        screen: NewsItemScreen,
        navigationOptions: {
            headerTitle: 'News Item'
        }
    }
});

const BottomTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
    Home: {
        screen: StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialIcons name="home" size={24} />
        }
    },
    News: {
        screen: StackNavigator,
        navigationOptions: {
            tabBarIcon: () => <MaterialCommunityIcons name="newspaper-variant-outline" size={24} />
        }
    }
})

export default createAppContainer(BottomTabNavigator);
```

Lo que deseo lograr es lo siguiente:

[image]

Como se puede observar, el `botón/tabs` inferior `[News]` tiene tres `botones/tabs` referenciales en la parte superior `[FEATURED], [RELEVANT], [SEARCH]` y, además de eso, recupera el nombre del `botón/tab` inferior y lo agrega al encabezado de la aplicación debajo de los `botones/tab` superiores.

Answer (score 1):

Hola he hecho este ejemplo como guia para tu solucion, lo que debes hacer es a lo que tu tienes, que lleva al componente home, renderizar los BottomTabs que al mismo tiempo dentro de esos componentes de bottom renderizarian los TopTabs de esa vista.. ya en el codigo lo entiendes mas

```
    import * as React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import { createMaterialBottomTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs';
import Splash from './app/resources/views/screens/Splash';

function HomeScreen() {
  return (
    <TabBottom.Navigator>
            <TabBottom.Screen name="SettingsScreen" component={SettingsScreen} />
            <TabBottom.Screen name="OtherScreen" component={OtherScreen} />
    </TabBottom.Navigator>
  );
}

function SettingsScreen() {
  return (
    <Tab.Navigator>
            <Tab.Screen name="TopScreen1" component={TopScreen1} />
            <Tab.Screen name="TopScreen2" component={TopScreen2} />
    </Tab.Navigator>
  );
}
function OtherScreen() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>OtherScreen!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
function TopScreen1() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>TopScreen1!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
function TopScreen2() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <Text>TopScreen2!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}

const Tab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();
const TabBottom = createMaterialBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();

export default function App() {
  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator>
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={HomeScreen} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
      </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

Se puede hacer de esta manera, pero siguiendo los ejemplos de la otra pregunta deberias tener todas esas vistas en archivos distintos e importarlos para tener una buena organización...

Comment: Entendí :) pero donde le agrego mi `loading Screen Splash` porque si lo agrego así solo me muestra el `screen splash` y, no el otro elemento que es el `tab top` y el `tab bottom` `<Stack.Navigator>
     <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={Splash} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
     <Stack.Screen name="Home" component={NavBottom} options={{headerShown:false}}/>
    </Stack.Navigator>
   </NavigationContainer>`

Comment: edite el codigo agregando la linea del splash, tener en cuenta que hay que cambiar el componente que se va a renderizar despues del Splash, quedaria asi teniendo en cuenta el ejemplo de esta pregunta:  this.goToScreen('HomeScreen')(esto se cambia el el archivo de splash)

Comment: Genial!! Ya aprendí más o menos como se ejecuta el `Splash`, tengo una curiosidad esta línea es `this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName)` para cuando se abre un enlace como lo había mencionado en mi anterior pregunta o no?

Comment: Una ultima pregunta como muestro el nombre del tab bottom en la parte superior del tab top así como la imagen si te das cuenta esta activado tab botton noticas y en la parte superior agrega el mismo nombre como titulo noticias

Comment: correcto,this.props.navigation.navigate(routeName) lo que hace es navegar a el componente que le pasamos(routeName)

Comment: para ponder el nombre en la parte superior entonces tendrias que quitar la propiedad headerShown y poner esta options={{headerLeft:null}}, la cual quitaria el boton de volver y tendrias el nombre alli arriba

Comment: el nombre que aparece alli es la propiedad `name`.. ahi entonces le pondrias noticias

Comment: Lo bueno tener conocimientos de programación es que no te dificulta tanto entender el código, oh, vaya tendré que consultar todas las propiedades para saber más de sus funciones nuevamente gracias :)

Comment: Me imagino que `options=` se le pueden pasar varias propiedades o solo una ?

Comment: se le pueden pasar multiples propiedades, aqui puedes ver mas https://reactnavigation.org/docs/headers/

Comment: `<Stack.Screen name="Home" component={NavBottom}  options={{headerLeft:null}}/>` pero eso solo me agrega un nombre en este caso `Home` para todos los botones BOTTOM, yo me refería imprimir el nombre de los botones inferiores en la parte superior al dar clck en elllos, si doy click en noticias mostrar la parte superior noticias, si doy click en tabs partidos mostrar en la parte superior Partidos

Comment: Es decir: `<TabBottom.Navigator>
   <TabBottom.Screen name="Noticias" component={NavNews} />
   <TabBottom.Screen name="Partidos" component={NavNews} />
  </TabBottom.Navigator>` esos nombre mostrarlo en la parte superior al dar click en ellos, intente agregarle esta propiedad `options={{headerLeft:null}}` pero no funciono.

Comment: mmm vale, no lo he hecho pero aqui hay un ejemplo, te podes guiar https://dev.to/easybuoy/combining-stack-tab-drawer-navigations-in-react-native-with-react-navigation-5-da

Comment: He editado mi pregunta con un problema similar pero con una diferente estructura de código.